# AWS S3 RTMP Videos streaming issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, video.js, rtmp

I have configured RTMP server in amazon s3, but i could not stream videos which i have uploaded. Can some one please help to resolve this issue.

Example Video:

```
rtmp://streaming.fabmarks.com/cfx/st/_definst_/mp4:fabmarks/production/uploads/1477899965981-hlgzzp3uhmoj00ha-96a34fb31b5affb11f5b6581ba5dc14d/How+good%E2%80%99s+your+SAT+SCORE.mp4
```

When i tested it in below URL:
http://d1k5ny0m6d4zlj.cloudfront.net/diag/CFStreamingDiag.html

I got following error message.

```
496310 - Connecting to rtmp://streaming.fabmarks.com:1935/cfx/st
497181 - Event: NetConnection.Connect.Success
497181 - Connect time: 871ms
497290 - StreamLen Response: 0
497290 - Playing: mp4:1477899965981-hlgzzp3uhmoj00ha-96a34fb31b5affb11f5b6581ba5dc14d/How+good%E2%80%99s+your+SAT+SCORE.mp4
497523 - Event: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
497523 - Event: NetStream.Play.Stop
```

Comment: You must use Flash of Adobe and embed it into HTML .

Comment: I am getting same error.

Comment: Well obviously this is a late reply but this could help some else. This type of error is shown when an object stored is not readable. .i.e object stored could be private. make it public